# How can I use excel's transpose function in mariaDB SQL(+BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, mariadb, subquery, flatten

I'm using MariaDB and I'm having a problem putting array data into vertical form.

| name | Location | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | A-SH-09-2-F[6] | 1 |
| item1 | B-SH-35-2-D[5] | 2 |
| item1 | B-SH-41-5[40] | 3 |
| item2 | A-RSH-03-2-D[10] | 1 |
| item2 | A-SH-08-4-K[3] | 2 |
| item3 | A-RSH-04-3-P[2] | 1 |

I use rownum to see how many locations an item has. It is a warehouse managing system and each item has locations. But I only need four locations for each item.

I want to put that into this form.

| name | Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | A-SH-09-2-F[6] | B-SH-35-2-D[5] | B-SH-41-5[40] |
| item2 | A-RSH-03-2-D[10] | A-SH-08-4-K[3] |  |
| item3 | A-RSH-04-3-P[2] |  |  |

I'm connecting BigQuery with MariaDB. So I can use other functions--subqueries, with, Pivot, Offset, UNNEST.
I can get this form, but I want to select it in one row.

```
Select am_p as amsku, sum(CAST(qty as numeric)) as sum, 
 COALESCE(MAX(CASE 
    WHEN il.rn = 1 THEN concat(location, '[', quantity, ']')
 END), '') AS LOC1,
 COALESCE(MAX(CASE 
    WHEN il.rn = 2 THEN concat(location, '[', quantity, ']')
 END), '') AS LOC2,
 COALESCE(MAX(CASE 
    WHEN il.rn = 3 THEN concat(location, '[', quantity, ']')
 END), '') AS LOC3,
 COALESCE(MAX(CASE 
    WHEN il.rn = 4 THEN concat(location, '[', quantity, ']')
 END), '') AS LOC4,
 name, 
 upc
from `inflow_loc.daily_order_for_picking2` as vdp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT item, location, quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY location) AS rn from `inflow_loc.inflow_loc`
  where location NOT LIKE '%ZSEARCH%' and
  quantity NOT LIKE '%-%'
) as il ON vdp.am_p = il.item
group by am_p, location, quantity, name, upc, rn
order by amsku, rn;
```

Loc1, Loc2, and Loc3 do not appear in the same row. BigQuery selects in this format.

| name | Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | A-SH-09-2-F[6] |  |  |
| item1 |  | B-SH-35-2-D[5] |  |
| item1 |  |  | B-SH-41-5[40] |

Comment: I'd go with `condition aggregation` - `select name, max(case when row_num = 1 then location else null end.), ...from <table> group by name`

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but I don't know why loc1, loc2, loc3 are not appear in the same row. I add that part too. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: First, try `max(case when il.rn =1 then coalesce(...) else null end)`.  Second, you have columns in your group by you shouldn't.  Based on your sample, just group by whatever column you are calling `name`.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please read the documentation when you have a problem. The advanced help tells you about markdown table format. Don't indent a table as code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the comment's suggestion.

```
Select am_p as amsku, sum(CAST(qty as numeric)) as sum, 
  max(CASE WHEN il.rn = 1 THEN COALESCE ( concat(location, '[', quantity, ']'), null) END ) AS LOC1,
  max(CASE WHEN il.rn = 2 THEN COALESCE ( concat(location, '[', quantity, ']'), null) END ) AS LOC2,
  max(CASE WHEN il.rn = 3 THEN COALESCE ( concat(location, '[', quantity, ']'), null) END ) AS LOC3,
  max(CASE WHEN il.rn = 4 THEN COALESCE ( concat(location, '[', quantity, ']'), null) END ) AS LOC4,
from `inflow_loc.daily_order_for_picking2` as vdp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT item, location, quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY location) AS rn from `inflow_loc.inflow_loc`
  where location NOT LIKE '%ZSEARCH%' and
  quantity NOT LIKE '%-%'
) as il ON vdp.am_p = il.item
LEFT OUTER JOIN `inflow_loc.sku_w_name` as na ON vdp.am_s=na.sku
LEFT OUTER JOIN `inflow_loc.sku_w_upc` as u ON vdp.am_s=u.sku
group by amsku
order by amsku;
```

I changed the 'coalesce' order behind the 'max'. And I only use groupby with 'amsku'(In question's example, it was item name.)